# Can Anyone please review my database after I did the Normalization ?.Any suggestion is appreciated

Tags: database-design, normalization, erd

1. User:
   **User_ID**,user_name,E-mail
2. Staff: **User_ID**,Fname,Lname,DOB
3. Student: **User_ID** fname Lname DOB
4. Lecture: **User_ID**
5. Admin: **User_ID**
6. Position ID : **P_ID**,ROLE_NAME,
7. Staff_position :**Staff_position_ID**,P_ID,user_ID
8. Programme: **Programme_ID** P_code P_name
9. Course: **Course_ID****Course_number** C_name C_level User_ID**
10. Co-programme: **Co-programme_id**,Course_ID,Programme_ID
11. Attendence:**Attendance_ID**,date,time
12. Attendance_course : **Attendance_course_ID**,Attendance_ID,Course_ID,date,time
13. Resources **Resource_ID** Type,size,Course_ID
14. Week_resources: **Week_resources_ID**,Week_number,term,resources_ID
15. Weekly_upload: **Weekly_upload_ID**, size,date, time,week_number
16. Message: **Message_ID**,user_ID,Body,date,time

Comment: Im doing this desing to desing a databse for an e-learning system.I did Chen ERD desing then Normalize it but Im not sure about having 3 PK in one Table and also the inheritance of PK.

Comment: Looks okay up to Course, but it gets a little fuzzy after that.  Care to elaborate on the thinking behind the Co-programme structure?  We can work on the details from there, if you like!

Comment: Are staff always users? Then why having a staff_id column?, you don't have a student_id column so why a staff_id?  Personally, I wouldn't do multi-columns PK. A constraint if you want but not as as PK.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have removed staff_ID and updated co_programme.And yes Avarkx I will appreciated if we can work on this database to improve it. I'm actually thinking about the Resources entity, do i need to add category attribute to make it possible uploading resources such as video,books and also be possible to be viewed by users?

Comment: Use. The. Party. Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I must admit that I have been a little disingenuous, I'm afraid: My comment on your question was merely a ruse to trick you into explaining your schema to a degree which would minimize the amount of guesswork that I ( or any other member ) would have to shoulder in attempting to give you feedback of any reasonable quality on your work thus far.  You expertly evaded my trap however, leaving me with no recourse but to rebuild your schema from the ground up, along the way explaining what I think you've overlooked or otherwise omitted, in the context of what I perceive your problem to be.

Secondly, with little to no explanation of the notation you are using, it is difficult to immediately discern the relationships, either data-wise or real, between the entities in your table list: Attributes such as *Position_ID* show up in the *Lecture* and *Admin* tables using the *ID* notation, indicating a key of some kind, but with no obvious source;  the description for *Course* is littered with *'s without any indication as to why, further going on to include a *User_ID* attribute - This latter curiosity is particularly confusing and leads me to believe the model isn't normalized to any sufficient level at all, though I can hypothesize a ( short ) number of reasons why this relationship exists; the purpose of *Co-Programme* continues to be evasive; just looking at *Consist of* causes my brow to furrow violently - Unlike the *User_ID* in *Course* conundrum, I cannot even begin to fathom what is going on there.

So now that I've gotten all of that off my chest, we'll start by reverse engineering the structure you've provided into a word problem ( which is what I was trying to get out of you in the beginning ):

> In the context of an e-learning system, we require a data model which can track our **students** as they participate in various **courses**, earning **credits** towards their **programs**.  Online **courses** are administrated by our **staff**, whom have expressed a desire to allow both themselves and **students** to upload various digital **resources** ( such as practice exams in the former case, or homework submission in the latter ) at varying **levels of accessibility**.  An **adjudicator**, for instance, would necessarily need to access the homework submissions of a **class** they preside over, whereas the fellow **students** of a **submitter** would necessarily not be able access such a **resource**.  We would also like to see some form of **audit trail** on the access of these resources ( though we don't really know why that's important ).

As [@ETL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/18625/etl) points out in his comment, the very first thing to consider is that [candidate keys make piss-poor primary keys](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/primarykey.htm), which are far better [left to the database for auto-generation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.sql.doc%2Fdoc%2Fprimary.keys.and.candidate.keys.html).  To be a little more clear on this point, despite frequent confusion between the two, there's [no such thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) as a primary key in relational algebra - this construct is instead referred to as a [minimal superkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey) in model theory.  With that in mind, I'll be applying [alternate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Alternate_key) ( also known as unique indexes or unique constraints ) on the minimal superkeys of our tables and letting the primary key be a nice, thin data type like `INTEGER`.  This practice will save you a lot of headache when foreign keys are involved and the data model needs updating.

"So, Mr. Words-A-Lot, are you going to help me or what?" or some such similar phrase may have indeed crossed your mind several times at this point.  Notice the description of your problem that I created above has a number of **bold** words.  These words, henceforth called nouns, in one way or another, are going to form the basic structure of your schema.  Some of them have already been realized in your original list, so some of this work has already been done, but for completeness ( and to illustrate good [OOAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_analysis_and_design) via [identifying objects](http://uml-tutorials.trireme.com/uml_tutorial_4.htm) ), we will touch on them anyway.  Without further ado, here's the general idea of something relatively close to what you'd eventually end up with to solve our little blurb above:

[image: Online Education]

Starting with relational model theory, meaning you can forget about things such as primary keys for now, "Noun-Verb" analysis is as follows:

A **Student** ( S ) accesses your online system with a ( *has a* ) **Username** ( UN ) and a **Staff** member ( which I'll be calling an **Adjudicator** ( A ), for my purposes ) *has a* **Username** as well.  Through this similarity, I can establish that there *is a* **User** ( U ) entity that *has a* **Username** ( UN ). `( A: B, C )`, meaning entity `A` is a "container" ( or a collection, later called a table ) with `B, C` as "attributes" ( or atomic traits, later called columns ).  To make things a little easier on me, we'll expand this notation to also include the minimal superkey in the notation, denoting this ( eventually alternate key ) of a particular container with a subscript `Un`, where `n` is merely used to indicate attributes sharing an equal `n` are part of the same key in that container, separating them from the possible inclusion of an independently unique key, `Um`, should such a condition be necessary ( protip: It won't be, so don't worry about it ).

> **User** ( U ) has a **Username** ( UN ), or ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub> )

Based on the schema originally presented, I assume these **Users** ( U ) sign up through email correspondence, indicating there also *is a* **Email** ( E ) entity which must be accounted for.  While this is presented as attribute of the **User** ( U ) container, being a member of the information technology crowd, I can't help but wonder who these people are who only have one email address.  In my experience, it's generally much, much easier ( and preferable ) to simply under-use the capabilities of a robust data model than it is to work around the limitations of one that has been under-designed, so I find myself insisting on a one-to-many relationship between the two.  **Email** ( E ) thus becomes a container, with an **Email Address** ( EA ) as an attribute.  To illustrate the many-to-one relationship between **Email** ( E ) and **User** ( U ), the latter becomes a "compound" attribute of the former, meaning that the **User** ( U ) container is treated as an attribute of the **Email** ( E ) container.  This begins to illustrate where foreign keys will materialize in the final structure, and can be notated as:

> ( E: EA<sub>U1</sub>, ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub> ) )

**Students** ( S ) and **Adjudicators** ( A ) are similar in other ways as well.  With attributes such as **First Name** ( FN ), **Last Name** ( LN ) and **Date of Birth** ( DOB ) in common, from a purely data-centric point of view, it becomes hazy as to whether they are indeed separate entities at all!  There is clearly a need to differentiate the two, or group them into their appropriate roles somehow, but the truth of this is as of yet unclear: Do the requirements dictate that a **User** ( U ) can not both be a **Student** ( S ) and a member of the **Staff** as well?  Does a **Teaching Assistant** not fill exactly this sort of **Position**, briefly alluded to in the original schema?

If a **Student** ( S ) can indeed also be an **Adjudicator** ( A ), it follows that there is a genuine one-to-one relationship between a **User** ( U ) and a **Student** ( S ) and also another genuine one-to-one relationship between a **User** ( U ) and an **Adjudicator** ( A ).  That is, a **User** ( U ) can be a ( *is a* ) **Student** ( S ) and a **User** ( U ) can be an ( *is an* ) **Adjudicator** ( A ).  A **User** ( U ) cannot be multiple of either however, barring clever online trickery.  Note than an **Administrator** could also be represented in this manner, through from the relative independence from the rest of the relationships in the model, I've omitted such an entity.

> ( S: ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub> )<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( A: ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub> )<sub>U1</sub> )

We know that both **Students** ( S ) and **Adjudicators** ( A ) have a **First Name** ( FN ), **Last Name** ( LN ) and a **Date of Birth** ( DOB ).  As such, we could do something silly, like the following:

> ( S: ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub> )<sub>U1</sub>, FN, LN, DOB )
>
> ( A: ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub> )<sub>U1</sub>, FN, LN, DOB )

But doing so would be in violation of, you guessed it, the [Third Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3NF).  In case the reason a specific user shouldn't have two **First Names** ( FN ) isn't immediately obvious, since both **Student** ( S ) and **Adjudicator** ( A ) have a minimal superkey ( again, denoted by U1 ) which consists of the entirety of the minimal superkey of **User** ( U ), non-prime attributes **First Name** ( FN ), **Last Name** ( LN ) and **Date of Birth** ( DOB ) are transitively dependent on **User** ( U ).  The correct arrangement is then to instead associate those attributes with the **User** ( U ) entity, as follows:

> ( S: ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub>, FN, LN, DOB )<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( A: ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub>, FN, LN, DOB )<sub>U1</sub> )

The next piece of the puzzle to tackle involves **Courses** ( C ) and **Programs** ( P ).  From my understanding, a **Program** ( P ) *is a* curriculum offered by a **Faculty**, which despite probably being the correct word to use, I chose **Department** ( D ) in my model and am not about to go and change it now.  The **Department** ( D ) of Mathematics can offer a number of different **Programs** ( P ), such as a Bachelors, a Bachelors with Honors, a Doctorate in Philosophy or a certification for a Chartered Accountant.  A simple, one-to-many relationship.

> ( P: PC<sub>U1</sub>, PN, ( D: DC<sub>U1</sub>, DN ) )

I imagine that in order to complete a **Program** ( P ) and win yourself the associated expensive piece of paper, there will be a number of **Program Requirements** ( PR ) - at least, that's the way I had to do it.  These requirements arise in the form of **Courses** ( C ), each of which have a ( *has a* ) **Credit Value** ( CV ) towards a **Program** ( P ).  As an aside, I've added **Course Level** ( CL ) as a compound attribute as well, though it has little value in the context of the model relationships.

> ( C: CC<sub>U1</sub>, CN, CV, ( CL: CLC<sub>U1</sub> ) )

As not all degrees are created equal, the **Program Requirements** ( PR ) may offer various choices and a particularly keen individual may opt to take a course in cryptology over one in data structures ( and subsequently get stuck listening to me ramble on the internet - not a desirable fate for the faint of heart ).  To keep **Program Requirements** ( PR ) flexible, we assume a one-to-many relationship between a **Program** ( P ) and **Program Requirements** ( PR ), with each of those requirements having a minimum number of **Required Credits** ( RC ) to meet the criteria.  The nature of this relationship is different from the other relationships we've seen thus far in that the **Program Requirement** ( PR ) deviates from the other entities by being a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) ( there is no reason a **Program** ( P ) couldn't require 20 credits from two separate **Course** ( C ) lists ) and thus has no candidate key.  While this reality doesn't affect our model notation in any detrimental manner ( we simply leave the subscript off the attribute list ), in terms of implementation on a database, we'll be using a surrogate key.  If you noticed above, I'm using a surrogate key ( the respective `<TableName>_PK` attribute ) on every table anyway.

> ( PR: RC, ( P: PC<sub>U1</sub>, PN, ( D: DC<sub>U1</sub>, DN ) ) )

Using this **Program Requirement** ( PR ) multiset, we can then define **Course** ( C ) lists which are able to satisfy those requirements.  That is to say, there *is a* **Program Requirement Course** ( PRC ) which is able to contribute in some way to the **Required Credits** ( RC ) of the requirements of a **Program** ( P ).  This construct allows us to set up a list of courses ( in a three of five case, for example ) or specifically require a list of courses to be completed.  If for some reason a particular **Program** ( P ) wished to alter the **Credit Value** ( CV ) of a particular **Course** ( C ) for its own purposes, an **Alternate Credit Value** ( ACV ) could be added as an attribute to the **Program Requirment Courses** ( PRC ) entity, but it's omitted from the diagram above, pretty much because I just thought of it now.  Note that **Program Course Requirement** ( PRC ) is a many-to-many relationship, allowing a specific **Course** ( C ) to be a requirement of any number of **Program Requirements** ( PR ) and **Program Requirements** ( PR ) to involve the completion of any number of **Courses** ( C ).

> ( PRC: *ACV*, ( PR: RC, ( P: PC<sub>U1</sub>, PN, ( D: DC<sub>U1</sub>, DN ) ) )<sub>U1</sub>, ( C: CC<sub>U1</sub>, CN, CV, ( CL: CLC<sub>U1</sub> ) )<sub>U1</sub> )

With the bulk of the work out of the way, it's really a matter of just tying the **Courses** ( C ) back to the **Students** ( S ) and **Adjudicators** ( A ) and continuing on to assert some of the more trivial relationships.  Since the definitions are getting a little long, I'm going to stop showing the attributes of the compound attributes and focus on the final structures we'll need instead.

We create a couple of many-to-many relationships in the form of **Adjudicator Course** ( AC ) and **Student Course** ( SC ):

> ( AC: A<sub>U1</sub>, C<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( SC: S<sub>U1</sub>, C<sub>U1</sub> )

An **Adjudicator** ( A ) which can instruct / administrate a **Course** ( C ) can now perform **Lectures** ( L ) for those **Courses** ( C ), designating a **Start Time** ( T1 ) and an **End Time** ( T2 ).  This is a multiset in my schema, though it could certainly be instead constrained to time blocks if desired.

> ( L: AC, T1, T2 )

A **Student** ( S ) who logs in to attend a **Lecture** ( L ) can be noted through a many-to-many **Student Attendance** ( SA ) relationship.

> ( SA: S<sub>U1</sub>, L<sub>U1</sub> )

A **Resource** ( R ) may be uploaded by a **User** ( U ) in the context of a specific **Course** ( C ).  An **Adjudicator** ( A ) should be allowed sufficient privileges to view the **Resources** ( R ) on their own **Courses** ( C ), whereas a **Student** ( S ) should only be allowed to see **Resources** ( R ) for a **Course** ( C ) as posted by an **Adjudicator** ( A ) of that course.  Such permissions are hand-waved by my data model as "business logic" to be handled through procedures, views and the application.  To expand on your comment, you could easily add a **Resource Type** ( RT ) here.

> ( R: U, C, RD, ( RT: RTC<sub>U1</sub>, RTN ) )

Finally, a **ResourceUser** ( RU ) table is added to simply keep track of the times ( **Date Accessed** ( DA ) ) which a particular **User** ( U ) accesses a specific **Resource** ( R ).

> ( RU: R, U, DA )

All in all, creating the following structure would solve the blurb:

> ( U: UN<sub>U1</sub>, FN, LN, DOB )
>
> ( E: U, EA<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( S: U<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( A: U<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( D: DC<sub>U1</sub>, DN )
>
> ( P: D, PC<sub>U1</sub>, PN )
>
> ( CL: CLC<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( C: CL, CC<sub>U1</sub>, CN, CV )
>
> ( PR: P, RC )
>
> ( PRC: PR<sub>U1</sub>, C<sub>U1</sub>, *ACV* )
>
> ( AC: A<sub>U1</sub>, C<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( SC: S<sub>U1</sub>, C<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( L: AC, T1, T2 )
>
> ( SA: S<sub>U1</sub>, L<sub>U1</sub> )
>
> ( *RT*: RTC<sub>U1</sub>, RTN )
>
> ( R: *RT*, U, C, RD )
>
> ( RU: R, U, DA )

Comment: Thank you for your help and I'm really sorry for my late replay as I was really busy recently. You ERD helps me to redraw my database and be aware of my mistakes, I have changed my database,and I am making an e-learning such as moodle so students can access their materials online and interact with oter users in the same time. have a look at my updated database and let me know what do u think abt it. thank you